# Optimizing performance of a SELECT query when using JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing two datetime columns, AddedTime and UsedTime. I would like to select the first 10 rows with the most recent AddedTime/UsedTime, while joining a related table. I am using the following query:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.GroupID, p.AddedTime, p.UsedTime, g.ID, g.Name, g.Image
FROM `products` AS p
JOIN `groups` AS g
ON p.GroupID = g.ID
ORDER BY GREATEST(AddedTime, UsedTime) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Both tables have more than 10k rows. I am running into performance issues when executing the query (it usually takes 700-2000 ms to run, and sometimes more). EXPLAIN says the query is using filesort, so I imagine this is an indexing issue. The products table has, among others, the following three indexes: AddedTime, UsedTime and added_or_used(AddedTime, UsedTime).

What can I do to optimize execution?

Comment: wrong RDMS ... @vishal  MySQL <> SQL Server (MSSQL)  ...  Also window functions are only supported in MySQL 8

Comment: Upgrade to MySQL 8 as *"MySQL 8.0.13 and higher supports functional key parts"*  see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) .. otherwise you would have to make a generated column and index that.. As `GREATEST(AddedTime, UsedTime)` requires one of these options..

Comment: So, if I am to judge by `ON p.ID = g.ID` your product IDs are of the same nature as your group IDs.  That does not make any sense.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - not sure I follow. Can you explain your suggestion a bit more?

Comment: ID in both tables are primary key?

Comment: @MikeNakis - I edited the original post to clarify. The products table has rows that indicate both the group ID (column GroupID) and product ids (column ID). It is indeed more properly represented as ON p.GroupID = g.ID

Comment: @bhuvneshpattnaik - no, only one is. (Btw, I edited the original post following the comment of MikeNakis, to clarify.)

Comment: *"not sure I follow. Can you explain your suggestion a bit more?"* Not sure how to explain it more easy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `GREATEST` function in `ORDER BY` clause, mysql can use any of the indices on the table.
If you are on version 8.0.13 or above you can setup a "[function index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts)"

On older version, you can try re-organizing the query like below to effectively use the indices:

```
select * from
(
    (select * from products order by added_time DESC LIMIT 10)
        UNION ALL
    (select * from products order by used_time DESC LIMIT 10)
) x 
order by GREATEST(added_time, used_time) LIMIT 10;
```

Note: Add join and other parts as required.

Comment: That should probably be `UNION DISTINCT` because the same row could be in the latest 10 of each inner query.

Answer (score 0):

A minor application change might solve the problem:  When "adding" a product, mark it as "used".  This means that simply `ORDER BY UsedTime DESC` will suffice (together with `INDEX(UsedTime)`).